# How to give credit without creating a pressure?

Tags: collaboration

I am creating some newsletters on which my colleagues can contribute if they want, in order for the info to be in one place and sent based on a schedule.
But it is not mandatory at all for them to contribute.

My problem is that I want to give them credit, and not leaving the impression that I created the thing entirely by myself, but without creating a pressure for other colleagues to contribute on this.
The scope is to share some info and not being on a list with which contributed the most (mainly in the eyes of my manager).

Comment: What is wrong with them just signing off anything they did?

Comment: You should absolutely credit people in the publication (and when talking about it, announcing its issue, etc). I'm confused what you think the alternative is - putting this publication out and letting people think you wrote it all? I'm sure many people won't even read it or pay any attention, so they won't care. But if they do feel put out (unlikely but possible) invite them to contribute in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how we typically did internal newsletters at my workplaces (all factories, from a few dozen employees to a few hundreds)

### Use an impersonal email

Who controls the mailbox is not important, so set up an impersonal email like communications@companyname.com. Not only it looks more professionally handled, it can also make some people less shy about contributing and it helps when you go on vacation and someone picks up the newsletter

### Give credits per piece(s)

Always - and I can't stress it enough - ALWAYS give credit to your writers, photographers, cartoonists, etc. Just a small credit below the title would be enough. Something like

**Project X wrapped up!**

written by ProjectManager, photos by SeniorEngineer

### Close the newsletter with an invitation

Encourage spontaneous contributions by closing the newsletter with a short invitation. It can be as vague or specific as you want - we usually mentioned deadlines for submitting for the next newsletter (if someone had something time-sensitive to send out before it became old news). For example:

**Have news?** Send your article and / or pictures to communications@companyname.com by Friday COB to be included in the very next newsletter!

And a few other pointers to make it easier for you to get contribution

### Casually remind people to send content for the newsletter

If you're present in a noteworthy event, like a workshop, training, project wrap-up, etc., ask the organizer to submit a short piece about the event to the newsletter and/or share a few photos